# How can I purify a sql query and replace all parameters with '?' using regex

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, regex

> For example I want to purify these queries

```
SELECT * FROM mytable1 WHERE field1  = 5;
UPDATE mytable1 SET field1 ="data" WHERE field1 = 5;
INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES("a", "\"b","c" );
```

> And get the result below

```
SELECT * FROM mytable1 WHERE field1 = ?;
UPDATE mytable1 SET field1=? WHERE field1 = ?;
INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES(?,?,?);
...
```

Comment: By hand is probably the best approach.

Comment: hi luk2302 thanks for bothering answering my question. Obviously the question is how to replace sql queries using regex not by hand... and there is a reason for it, I want to get the purified queries for statistics.

Comment: AxelH no ignores, just all parameters and values (numbers and strings)

Comment: AxelH the answering is no. I dont need just the query type (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT). I need the whole query more. I don't want to get statistics using any other suggestion. I need to get statistics of the purified sql query. The question remains simple. How to purify sql queries from dynamic parameters

Comment: `(=\s*)(\S+?(?=\s|;))` replace with `$1?` for select and update queries (this only catches `=`, so other methods won't work unless you specify them)

Comment: To show me that you have tried to solve this yourself and not simply posted your requirements on SO hoping for a free code ... but this is my last comment, you don't seems to understand StackOverflow so I will not grant you more of my time.

Comment: ctwheels thank you, this seems useful as a first approach

Comment: AxelH I posted my useful question here to share the solution with the community for now and forever. You are the one who is wasting my time and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to work with a 3rd party lib instead of using regex you may try [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki) to make that kind of sql string modification. Below is an example for replacing string and long values in all kinds of statements.

```
import net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.LongValue;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.StringValue;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.Statement;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.util.deparser.ExpressionDeParser;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.util.deparser.SelectDeParser;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.util.deparser.StatementDeParser;

public class TestTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSQLParserException {
        String sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM mytable1 WHERE field1  = 5;";
        String sql_2 = "UPDATE mytable1 SET field1 ='data' WHERE field1 = 5;";
        String sql_3 = "INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES('a','b','c' );";

        System.out.println(modify(sql_1));
        System.out.println(modify(sql_2));
        System.out.println(modify(sql_3));
    }
    public static String modify(String sql) throws JSQLParserException{
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        ExpressionDeParser expressionDeParser = new ExpressionDeParser() {
            @Override
            public void visit(StringValue stringValue) {
                this.getBuffer().append("?");
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(LongValue longValue) {
                this.getBuffer().append("?");
            }
        };
        SelectDeParser selectDeparser = new SelectDeParser(expressionDeParser,buffer );
        expressionDeParser.setSelectVisitor(selectDeparser);
        expressionDeParser.setBuffer(buffer);
        StatementDeParser stmtDeparser = new StatementDeParser(expressionDeParser, selectDeparser, buffer);
        Statement stmt = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
        stmt.accept(stmtDeparser);
        return stmtDeparser.getBuffer().toString();
    }
}

// output: 
//SELECT * FROM mytable1 WHERE field1 = ?
//UPDATE mytable1 SET field1 = ? WHERE field1 = ?
//INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

For more examples visit [the example pages of jsqlparser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-building).

For mvn or jar download [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jsqlparser/jsqlparser/1.1)

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Playing with regular expressions was too complicated for advanced sql queries. But I guess this library can handle them all. Thank you

Comment: Using regexp in those hierarchical languages, that could have comments and quoted strings is always very problematic. If a parser is available one should try it.